# Is it possible to put a wx.window (frame/panel) over a wx.MenuBar?

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to know if it's possible to put a frame or a panel over a menubar using wxpython?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May I ask why?  I can't think of a use for this, so I'm curious what one would be.

Comment: I want to make my own caption :)
Is there a way to change the caption to a better thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only chance is to write some Custom Menu, which could be bit difficult but doable. So basically instead of using system menu etc, you create windows inside your main frame which look like menu.